# Thrift + ActiveMQ Integration

Tags: architecture, activemq-classic, thrift

My company is currently investigating the integration of Thrift and ActiveMQ. We'd like to set up a language-independant service layer that runs on a single http server, with each thrift service being able to communicate with other thrift services through ActiveMQ. I have been unable thus far to find anyone else who has tried to implement this. I'm curious as to how others might go about implementing this, and whether or not there is documentation on doing so.

The current prototype uses a simple python server that hosts various thrift services. Within each of the service calls (i.e., update a setting), an ActiveMQ message is created and sent to a particular queue (i.e., a settings service for one app sends out an update message to another). A service listener is created for each implementation of the settings service that is able to scan the appropriate queue and detect when a relevant message is sent over. This listener then uses Thrift to access the appropriate service for that particular application.

I'm trying to figure out a way to allow a service to serve a thrift object, but also receive ActiveMQ messages without the need to create these listeners, but I have been unable to find any resources for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description you have at least to options, IMHO:

**(1) Make use of the serialization part** and write the serialized messages into the queue. The listeners deserialize them and feed them to a (local) processor instance, which triggers the rest of the processing.

**(2) Write a dedicated transport** for it to support ActiveMQ. It may help to encapsulate the serialization/deserialization stuff better and provide the usual call interface to the clients/processors.

Two more tips:

- Have a look at [THRIFT-812](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-812), which demonstrates the combination with ZeroMQ
- Have a look at the Thrift documentation for `oneway` methods. You'll find them quite useful for message queueing scenarios.

---

What do i mean by feeding incoming data into a local processor instance? Ok, here's a piece of code which I wrote some time ago to demonstrate that. It is written in Delphi, but should be simple enough to enable you to translate it into any other language of your choice. The request data are passed and expected as JSON in this particluar case, hence the JSON protocol.

```
class procedure TTextToolJsonServer.Process( const stmIn, stmOut : TStream);
var handler   : Samples.TTextTool.Iface;
    processor : IProcessor;
    protIn, protOut : IProtocol;
begin
  protIn  := TJSONProtocolImpl.Create(
               TStreamTransportImpl.Create(
                 TThriftStreamAdapterDelphi.Create( stmIn, FALSE), nil));

  protOut := TJSONProtocolImpl.Create(
               TStreamTransportImpl.Create(
                 nil, TThriftStreamAdapterDelphi.Create( stmOut, FALSE)));

  handler   := TTextToolHandler.Create;
  processor := Samples.TTextTool.TProcessorImpl.Create( handler);
  processor.Process( protIn, protOut);
end;
```

Comment: Could you expand on feeding them the a local processor instance?

Comment: Edited into the answer.